# What is the equivalent in .NET for ChrToOemA from VB6?

Tags: .net, vb6

I'm migrating an application from VB6 to .NET and in VB6 i have a a call to this method: CharToOemA. I don't understand what it does and how I can reproduce this functionality.
The line in VB6 is like this: Call CharToOemA(Text, Text), where Text is a string.

Is there an equivalent in .NET for CharToOemA from VB6? If there isn't how can i implement this in .NET?

Answer (score 1):

[CharToOem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647473(VS.85).aspx) is a Windows API call, not a native part of VB6. I'm guessing the VB6 is using it to convert a native VB6 string into an [OEM](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/08/389527.aspx) string. OEM is the character set usually used by console programs.

I don't know **why** your VB6 code wants to create an OEM string. That would be the first thing I would investigate - what is the VB6 trying to achieve? There may be an entirely different way to achieve the goal in .Net.

You may be able to replace CharToOem with the .Net [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert.aspx), although you might have to specify exactly which OEM character set you want to use (OEM United States, OEM Multilingual Latin I...).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class. It defines several different character encodings (such as [UTF-8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx) or [ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx)) and can be used to [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert.aspx) between them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you might not have to use it at all. [Strings in .NET](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html) are always in Unicode encoding.